# How to Determine Units of an F-Curve

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, units

I'm working on a script dealing with keyframes and I need to change the behavior based on the keyframes' values' units (e.g. meters for Location & degrees/radians for Rotation). How can I determine the units after getting the f-curves/keyframes?

I'm unable to find the property's units from the [Keyframe class](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Keyframe.html).

Property has a [unit](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Property.html?highlight=unit#bpy.types.Property.unit) property, but I'm not sure how to get there from the F-Curve/Keyframe. F-Curve has a [data_path](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FCurve.html?highlight=fcurve#bpy.types.FCurve.data_path) which returns the RNA string, but I'm not sure how to use that to get the actual Property with the unit property.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless someone knows of a better way, this seems to work:
`unit = obj.bl_rna.properties[fcurve.data_path].unit`